# Trim, normalise and plot CCF Data

Tags: python-3.x, normalization, trim

In the code below I have attempted to normalise my CCF data, which is publicly available from the DACE website. I would like to trim the original data (the original data which gives a "V" shape) and normalize the data (which should give the values between 0.0 and 1.0)

```
This is what I have tried, 


import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import pandas as pd
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from sklearn import preprocessing
%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib widget


data_dir = glob.glob('/Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/harpn_sun_release_package_ccf_2018/2018-01-18/*.fits')

# Empty lists for storage
lams = []
fluxs = []

for file_path in data_dir:
    hdul = fits.open(file_path)
    data = hdul[1].data
    h1 = hdul[1].header
    w = WCS(h1, naxis=1, relax=False, fix=False)
    flux = data[1]
    lam = w.wcs_pix2world(np.arange(len(flux)), 0)[0]
    lams.append(lam)
    fluxs.append(flux)
    
# Calculate normals
norm_array = np.array([data])
normal = (data - data.min())/(data.max() - data.min())

# Residuals data plot
fig_norm, ax_norm = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

for i in range(len(lams)):
    ax_norm.plot(lams[i], normal[i], linewidth=1)


#view normalized values
plt.show(norm)
```